# Como usar $broadcast(), $emit() e $on() no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Entendi que o `$emit()` e o `$broadcast` são emissores e o `$on` é um listener de evento. Estou trabalhando com testes unitários e não estou conseguindo acessar a seguinte função:

**eventHandler.service.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("app")

    .service('EventHandler', EventHandler);

EventHandler.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$animate', '$state', '$stateParams', '$sanitize', '$q', '$uibModal', 'toastr',
    'storage', 'StorageService', 'LogService', 'LanguageResource', 'LoginService', 'StcpUtilsService', 'DAOService',
    'CSRF', 'Authorization', 'ShortcutService', 'data_login', 'PermissionsService', 'BusinessLogicService', 'DebugMode'
]; 

function EventHandler($rootScope, $location, $animate, $state, $stateParams, $sanitize, $q, $uibModal, toastr, storage, StorageService,
                      LogService, LanguageResource, LoginService, StcpUtilsService, DAOService, CSRF,
                      Authorization, ShortcutService, data_login, PermissionsService, BusinessLogicService, Debug) {

    var animate;
    /* = parameters.$animate || $animate; */
    var rootScope;
    /* = parameters.$rootScope || $rootScope; */
    var scope;
    /* = parameters.$scope; */
    var _toastr;
    /* = parameters.toastr || toastr; */
    var _storage;
    /* = parameters.StorageService || StorageService; */
    var location;
    /* = parameters.$location || $location; */
    var log;
    /* = parameters.LogService ? parameters.LogService.log : LogService.log || LogService.log; */
    var language;
    /* = parameters.LanguageResource || LanguageResource; */
    var shortcut;
    var t;
    var dao;
    var DebugMode;

    return {
        initialize: initialize_component,
        onCheckSession: onCheckSessionHandle,
        onLogin: onLoginHandle,
        onLogout: onLogoutHandle,
        onStateChangeError: onStateChangeErrorHandle,
        onHideMenuCheck: onHideMenuCheckHandle,
        onSetInstance: onSetInstanceHandle,
        onRemoveInstance: onRemoveInstanceHandle,
        onGetInstanceName: onGetInstanceNameHandle,
        onGetInstanceId: onGetInstanceIdHandle,
        onGetOperatorLogged: onGetOperatorLoggedHandle,
        onOperatorIsLogged: onOperatorIsLoggedHandle,
        onShakeMenu: onShakeMenuHandle,
        onCheckInstance: onCheckInstanceHandle,
        onSave: onSaveHandle,
        onDelete: onDeleteHandle,
        onInterceptError: onInterceptErrorHandle,
        onChangeOperatorPassword: onChangePasswordHandle,
        onGetTransfer: onGetTransferHandle,
        onOpenChangeModuleDialog: onOpenChangeModuleDialogHandle,
        onChangeSubModule: onChangeSubModuleHandle,
        onDisplaySelectionInstance: onDisplaySelectionInstanceHandle,
        onGetInstances: onGetInstancesHandle,
        onCheckModule: onCheckModuleHandle,
        // onDataToPersist: onDataToPersistHandle
    };

    // function onDataToPersistHandle() { rootScope.$on('dataToPersist', onDataToPersist); }
    function onRemoveInstanceHandle() {
        rootScope.$on('removeInstance', onRemoveInstance);
    }        

    function onRemoveInstance(ev, args) {
        onCheckSession(ev, args);

        if (ev.defaultPrevented === false) {
            _storage[storage].del("instance_id");
            _storage[storage].del("instance_name");
            _storage.local.del("instance_name");
            _storage.local.del("instanceSelected");
            _storage.session.del("instanceSelected");
            rootScope.instanceSelected = undefined;
            delete rootScope.displaySelectionInstance;
            delete rootScope.instance_id;
            delete rootScope.instance_name;
        }
    } //...
```

Estou fazendo os testes da seguinte maneira, porém não consigo testar a função "onRemoveInstance", me indicaram aplicar algum emitter pra que eu possa conseguir acessa-lá. E preciso saber como fazer o ev.defaultPrevented ser false.

**testEventHandlerService.Spec.js**

```
describe('Testing EventHandler', function () {
beforeEach(module('app'));

var srv, rootScope, injector, httpBackend, animate, scope, location, loginService, _toastr, _storage, dao, log, language;

beforeEach(inject(function (EventHandler,_$injector_, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $animate, $location, LoginService, toastr, storage, StorageService, LogService, DAOService, LanguageResource) {
  injector = _$injector_;
  srv = EventHandler;
  rootScope = $rootScope;          
  animate = $animate;
  location = $location;
  loginService = LoginService;
  _toastr = toastr;
  _storage = StorageService;
  log = LogService;
  language = LanguageResource;
  dao = DAOService;


  srv.initialize({
      $rootScope: rootScope,
      $animate: animate,
      $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
      $location: location,
      _toastr: toastr,
      _storage: StorageService,
      log: LogService,
      language: LanguageResource,
      dao: DAOService,
  })

//   rootScope.$on('doLogin', null);      
}));    

it('testing if the onRemoveInstance function', function(){  
    srv.ev = {defaultPrevented: false}; //testando para ver se da certo      
    srv.onRemoveInstance();       
    rootScope.$emit('removeInstance', srv.onRemoveInstance); 
});

it('testing if the onChangeSubModule function', function(){        
    srv.onChangeSubModule();       
    rootScope.$emit('changeSubModule', srv.onChangeSubModule);   
});
```

Se possível alguém pode me dar um exemplo em tempo real sobre o uso dos três?

Comment: Você tem que fazer sua função no "Angular way" de fazer, respondi logo abaixo

Comment: @Jackson posso passar o 
$scope.$emit('onRemoveInstance', $scope.ALGUMACOISA); 
dentro da minha iteração de teste?

Comment: Sim, você pode chamar o $emit('onRemoveInstance') dentro do $on('onRemoveInstance'). Mas para que você quer fazer isso? Você vai fazer um loop infinito.

Comment: @Jackson Tenho um service no angularjs com a função à cima e preciso aplicar um teste unitário nela. Estou tentando chama-lá de várias maneiras e não consigo acessa-lá e me falaram que pelos emitters vou conseguir. Mas nunca usei e estou tendo dificuldade

Comment: com os `$emit` com certeza você vai conseguir. Ele é uma chamada global. edite a pergunta com o código para eu entender melhor

Comment: @Jackson a pergunta foi editada. Espero que melhore o entendimento

Comment: Ok, pelo que estou vendo, você não consegue acessar porque teu `$on` está encapsulado de uma função pura do javascript, você precisa criar a função a partir do `$scope`. Por exemplo tua função  =>

function onRemoveInstanceHandle() {
        rootScope.$on('removeInstance', onRemoveInstance);
    }... Remova tudo e deixe apenas o $scope.on('removeInstance', onRemoveInstance)

Comment: Se não estiver entendendo, tente adaptar um plunker simples com apenas uma chamada disparando um alerta. Se não for possível, vamos tentar por outro caminho

Comment: @Jackson consegui entrar na função **onRemoveInstance** porém ela não está verificando o if. Você teria alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer isso? Estava tentando passar como um objeto como está no caso de teste. Isso está certo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66606/discussion-between-jackson-and-alexia).

Answer (score 4):

O `$emit` e o `$broadcast` são muito parecidos. Como você disse, ambos são para disparar algo. Vou tentar explicar de forma bem simples

O `$broadcast` chama o evento de todo mundo que está "abaixo" dele, seriam os filhos mesmo.
Já o `$emit` chama todos os eventos com aquele nome. Ele é um cara que dispara globalmente.

O `$on` é o listener, então ele será ativado quando for chamado por um `$emit` ou `$broadcast`

Não sei o que você quer fazer aí nesse seu código, mas seria algo desse tipo:

```
$scope.$on('onRemoveInstance', function(ev, args) {
onCheckSession(ev, args);

        if (ev.defaultPrevented === false) {
            _storage[storage].del("instance_id");
            _storage[storage].del("instance_name");
            _storage.local.del("instance_name");
            _storage.local.del("instanceSelected");
            _storage.session.del("instanceSelected");
            rootScope.instanceSelected = undefined;
            delete rootScope.displaySelectionInstance;
            delete rootScope.instance_id;
            delete rootScope.instance_name;
        }
});

// Aqui embaixo eu chamo minha função. Essa minha chamada pode ser feita em qualquer lugar do código, inclusive em outro arquivo javascript em um outro controller.

$scope.$emit('onRemoveInstance', $scope.ALGUMACOISA);
```

Como pedido, estou deixando aqui também este [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/am6IDw?p=preview) mostrando na prática isso.

Aproveite e leia também sobre [$ROOTSCOPE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) na documentação oficial do AngularJS